# awk compare two elements in the same line with regular expression

Tags: awk

I have very long files where I have to compare two chromosome numbers present in the same line. I would like to use awk to create a file that take only the lines where the chromosome numbers are different.

Here is the example of my file:

```
CHROM   ALT
    1   ]1:1234567]T
    1   T[1:2345678[
    1   A[12:3456789[
    2   etc...
```

In this example, I wish to compare the number of the chromosome (here '1' in the CHROM column) and the number that is between the first bracket ([ or ]) and the ":" symbol. If these numbers are different, I wish to print the corresponding line.

Here, the result should be like this:

```
    1   A[12:3456789[
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '$1+0 != $2+0' file
    1   A[12:3456789[
    2   etc...
```

Comment: Hey, why do you cast to a number here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Which part of the code should I change if I have several column between these two columns?

Comment: You're welcome. Post a followup question with whatever your different data looks like.

Comment: @hek2mgl by using `[` and `]` as the FS $1 is `<blanks>1    A` and $2 is `12:3456789` so by adding zero I'm stripping off everything after the leading digits and removing leading blanks from each.

Answer (score 3):

This requires GNU awk for the 3 argument `match()` function:

```
gawk 'match($2, /[][]([0-9]+):/, a) && $1 != a[1]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for the different answers.

Here are how my data looks like with several columns:

```
CHROM   POS       ID      REF   ALT
    1   1000000   123:1     A   ]1:1234567]T
    1   2000000   456:1     A   T[1:2345678[
    1   3000000   789:1     T   A[12:3456789[
    2   ...       ...       .   ...
```

My question is: how do I modify the previous code, when I have several columns?

Comment: In awk, `$1` is the value of the first column, `$2` is the value of the second column, and so on. With this data, you want to extract the chromasome number from the fifth column.

Comment: Also, this data is pertinent to your question: instead of posting an answer (which this is not) you should edit your question and put this information there